# BPM / Workflow software for personal use

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, workflow

I am aware of the zero-code debate between programming languages and BPM systems. My personal summary is: on the one hand, there will always be some amount of programming; on the other hand, non-programmers (in general, and no offence intended) often find difficult to structure business processes as algorithms, let alone to construct running programs.

However, I am somewhat at the middle of this debate: I am no longer in IT, but I manage far better than my fellow (mathematician) end users with my (modest) administrative tasks. Having worked in systems for many years, I can program some scripting (a few lines in PHP or java, say), although I neither like nor excel at programming. Also, I am not afraid of installing a Linux distro, administering packages, mysql, etc.

So, the question is: can you recommend a very light software package to manage processes, with minimum amount of programming? For instance, I am managing some paperwork with Trello, but it is not easy to integrate a small department (a couple of collaborators, say), automate some steps, send e-mails for pending tasks... I am thinking about giving a try to Processmaker, but it seems a bit gigantic for my needs. I do not need a strict adherence to BPM standards, either.

Requirements:

- Open source, zero cost. Free in every sense.
- Self-hosted. I have my own computer and domain in my institution.
- Web-based, no program download. A casual user (a student, for example) could check their document on their mobile.

Any suggestion (or indication that I must abandon and look for a programmer) will be welcome.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Business_Process_Modeling_Notation_tools ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BPMN_2.0_engines ?